# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support security issues

Tags: apt, updates, repository

Adding the anbox repository gives me these weird issues.
i used the --allow-insecure-repositories but that only works for my update
Please help.

````
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jconti/gnome3/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/peppermintos/p9-release/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://deb.fdmpkg.org bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 38832685B6D09383
E: The repository 'http://deb.fdmpkg.org bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.```
````

Comment: There are at least two separate problems. Regarding the `... does not have a Release file` messages, this typically means that the PPA doesn't offer packages for your version of Ubuntu. For example, `https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3` is only available up to Raring Ringtail, which is from 2013. For newer Ubuntu releases, you need to look for a different PPA that offers packages for the release you use (probably Groovy Gorilly from last October).

Comment: Regarding the `... The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available...` messages, those repos are signed with a public / private key combination. You need to get the public key, so `apt` can verify the signature. You'll want to look into the `apt-key` command (and maybe public / private keys in general).

Comment: How do i install ANBOX on 20.10 in that case?

Comment: https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install.html